# Is there a way to scan indexes in an ArrayList? .nextint .nextln etc?

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have an ArrayList called data.

Each index in data contains a line of words and numbers.
for example:

```
data(0) contains: Bob Sinclair, BS776, 87.5, 23.4, 20.1, 50.2

data(1) contains: Paul Paulson, PP009, 98.3, 12.6, 34.0, 22.5
```

...plus 8 more

Is there a way I can separate each into 6 objects (Name, Student Number, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4)?

I need to add the scores together afterwards for a total, but am not asking for help with that part, only mentioning it because the numbers can't be a string because they need to be added (or maybe they can be a string, /shrug, I'm a noob).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are more than one ways to skin a cat:

#### First: String.split()

```
String[] parts = inputString.split(','); //split the input
String name = parts[0];                  //get first part. 
double[] scores = new double[4];         //create array for doubles 
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {                 //fill array of doubles --> array index checking might be needed!
    scores[i]=Double.parseDouble(scores[i+2]);
}
```

However, as this deals with floating point numbers, you should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as why they can show funny results... Or, you could use BigDecimals

```
BigDecimal exactResult = BigDecimal.valueOf(scores[i+2]);
```

#### Second possiblity: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(inputString);
s.useDelimiter(",");
String name = s.next();
double[] scores = new double[4];         //create array for doubles 
String someCode = s.next();
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {                 //fill array of doubles 
    scores[i]=Double.parseDouble(s.next()); //null check might be needed!
}
```

#### Third: Using a pattern

```
//this pattern is very ugly (unsacalable, unmaintainable), but should work for now as poc...
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^,]*),\\s*([^,]*),\\s*([^,]*),\\s*([^,]*),\\s*([^,]*),\\s*([^,]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if(matcher.matches()) {
   String name = group(1);
   String someCode = group(2);
   double[] scores = new double[4];         //create array for doubles 
   for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {                 //fill array of doubles 
      scores[i]=Double.parseDouble(s.group(i+3)); //null check might be needed!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can be strings, you can then use the string split method to separate them into 6 string, and use the Float.parseFloat("number in string format here").

Link to the Class API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

That is what you do in `Object Oriented Programming`

i.e. create a class `Student` with properties `Name, Student Number, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4`

```
class Student {
  String name;
  int num;
  int score1;
  int score2;
  int score3;
  int score4;
  // getters setters here
}
```

And populate this `Student` class's instance from each element of your `ArrayList`.

```
List<Student> slist = new ArrayList<Student>();
for (String str : list) {
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    // some validation here for generated arr
    student student = new Student();
    student.setName(arr[0]);
    student.setName(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
    // populate rest of fields
    slist.add(student);
}
System.out.println(slist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
for (String str : data) {

      //use split with , on each string here

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class, wich gets one data-object, i suppose it's a string, as parameter for your constructor.

If it's a string, you can separate it by `string.split(",");`

With your class, you can easily create methods to get all your wanted values in sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Bob Sinclair, BS776, 87.5, 23.4, 20.1, 50.2");
list.add("Paul Paulson, PP009, 98.3, 12.6, 34.0, 22.5");
for (String str : list) {
String[] parts = str.split(", ");
// create structure which you need and put data there
// parts[0] - student, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your data up into a class, and then store instances of that class in your `ArrayList`.

Say you have a class `Player`:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private List<Float> scores;

    public Player(String name){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Float> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }
    public void setScores(List<Float> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }
}
```

You would then create your ArrayList as `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>`.

Using the getters and setters of the Player objects, you can then retrieve each individual attribute and do with them what you like.

So to get just the name of that instance, you would do:
`players.get(0).getName()` or the same for any variable stored in the player class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` method from `String` class like this, supposing that `data` has the `List<String>` type and each line has exactly the structure you described:

```
for(String s: data) {
    String[] line = s.split(",");
    // use each element in line
    String studentName = line[0];
    String studentNumber = line[1];
    double score1 = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
    double score2 = Double.parseDouble(line[3]);
    double score3 = Double.parseDouble(line[4]);
    double score4 = Double.parseDouble(line[5]);
}
```